# Controlled react input is breaking maxLength attribute in chrome when undo/redo is performed

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have built a textfield which converts provided input to uppercase using react which accepts maxLength of 5 characters.

Issue:
When I try to do undo and redo operations, the text field is allowing more characters than specified in maxLength HTML attribute.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Goto link: https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-uppercase-material-ui-forked-95ww4t?file=/src/App.js
2. It has a text input which converts given text to uppercase and also allows maximum of 5 characters
3. Type 'abcdef'. You can seen 'ABCDE' in text field due to max length restriction
4. Press 'ctrl+z' for 5 times
5. Press 'ctrl+y' for redo
6. Now you can see 7 characters inside the text box 'ABCDEAA' which should not be allowed as per the maxLength specification.

I'm facing this issue in chrome & edge browsers (Chromium based browsers) but not in firefox. Am I doing anything wrong here or is it an issue needs to be fixed by Chrome or React.

Code:

```
export default function App() {


const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const onValueChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Text Field uppercase</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input"
        value={value}
        maxLength="5"
        onChange={onValueChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't work well in Firefox either. It can accept more than 5 characters. Besides, 'ctrl+z' and 'ctrl+y' don't work well in the browsers. If you want to use uppercase, I think using CSS style is more convenient. You can refer to the following code, it works well in all the three browsers:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Text Field uppercase</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input"
        defaultValue=""
        maxLength="5"
        style={{ textTransform: "uppercase" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou,
Thanks for your response. Yes we can implement this using CSS. Is there any way you think it can be achieved with the onChangeHandler as I need to sanitize some characters like "<", ">" during onChange. At that time also this issue will occur.

Comment: I got your point. I can reproduce the issue even without React. For example, [this simple sample](https://jsfiddle.net/k37sjy6r/) can reproduce the issue. It occurs with chromium browsers when using 'ctrl+z' 'ctrl+y' plus changing input value with maxim string length restriction. I think it's an issue with chromium. I suggest report this on [chromium site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou. Let me raise it in Chromium.

Comment: I have filed a ticket in Chromium. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1423322